# how does Intellij recognizes synthetic 'log' property with Groovy AST @log4j

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

how does the synthetic field get Intellij recognition,in groovy AST, even before the project was compiled.
Specifically for `@log4j` AST annotation?

Comment: It probably compiles it, and scans the synthetic fields

Comment: does it compile on the fly?my guess was towards the value property of the annotation

Comment: I think they actually added support for the built-in Groovy AST annotations. I don't get code completion when I write my own and they made a point about @Builder annotation support being added in 15.

Answer (score 0):

They do it with Groovy DSL scripting framework. And not just Log4J but 
Bindable, Singleton, Newify, Delegate etc all are implemented using [GDSL](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/GRVY/Scripting+IDE+for+DSL+awareness).